# Sails.js can't access data model in the middleware: Unexpected token

Tags: sails.js

sails.js newbie here.

I can't access my `User` model within my middleware. It says unexpected token.

Here's my middleware,

```
        isAuthenticated: (function(){   
            return function authHandler(req, res, next) {

                let payload;   
                try {          
                    payload = decode(req);          
                    let expTime = moment.tz(payload.exp, 'GMT').toDate();
                    let currentTIme = moment.tz('GMT').toDate();

                    if (currentTIme > expTime) {    
                        return res.status(401).json({message: 'JWT token expired.'}); 
                    } else {   
>>                      const user =  await User.findOne({id: payload.id}); 

                        if (user) {                     
                            req.payload = {                 
                                userId: user.id                 
                            }; 
                            return next()                   

                        } else {
                            return res.status(401).json({message: 'User doesn\'t exist.'});

                        }      
                    }          

                } catch (err) {
                    return res.serverError();       
                }              


            }                  
        })()                   
    }
```

I am trying to setup a authentication middleware. In my global settings `models` is set to `true`.

I tried, `sails.models.user` but even for that I get unexpected token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `async` keyword, `async function(..){....await....}`.
The `await` keyword is only valid inside async functions.